# eclipselink doesn't care about foreign key constraint, but the DBMS does

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, foreign-keys, eclipselink

I have an issue with JPA and a relation manyToMany. I use an inheritance strategy for both sides of the relation. Jpa doesn't take into account the foreign key constraints, but mysql does when I use workbensh to delete a characters who is bound to a movie for example.

I don't understand how the JPA can pass through the constraints.

the first class hierarchy :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPEOEUVRE",discriminatorType = 
DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Table(name="Oeuvre")

public abstract class EtyOeuvre extends EtyAbstract implements 
ItCompositeInfo,Comparable<EtyOeuvre> {

    @ManyToMany(cascade ={ CascadeType.PERSIST},fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="oeuvres_characters", joinColumns = 
              @JoinColumn(name="oeuvres_ID"),inverseJoinColumns = 
              @JoinColumn(name="characters_ID"))
    @OrderBy("last_name,first_name ASC")
    protected List<EtyCharacter> characters  = new 
                                 LinkedList<EtyCharacter>();

}

@MappedSuperclass 
public class EtyOeuvreCinematographic extends EtyOeuvre {

}

@Entity @DiscriminatorValue("1") 
 public class EtySerieTv extends EtyOeuvreCinematographic {

}
```

And the second class hierarchy

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPEHUMAN",discriminatorType = 
public abstract class EtyHuman extends EtyAbstract implements 
Comparable<EtyHuman>{

}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
public class EtyCharacter extends EtyHuman {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "characters",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch 
                = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<EtyOeuvre> oeuvres;
}
```

and this is the DLL code for the join table

```
CREATE TABLE `oeuvres_characters` (
  `characters_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `oeuvres_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`characters_ID`,`oeuvres_ID`),
  KEY `FK_oeuvres_characters_oeuvres_ID` (`oeuvres_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_oeuvres_characters_characters_ID` FOREIGN KEY 
 (`characters_ID`) REFERENCES `human` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_oeuvres_characters_oeuvres_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`oeuvres_ID`) 
REFERENCES `oeuvre` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
oeuvres_characters
```

the classes I really use in my code are EtyCharacter and for instance EtySerieTv.

Thanks for help :)

edit.

this is the SQl generated when I delete a character :

```
  DELETE FROM oeuvres_characters WHERE ((characters_ID = ?) AND (oeuvres_ID 
  = ?))
    bind => [76, 1]]]

 DELETE FROM human WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (VERSION = ?))
   bind => [76, 1]]]
```

you can see that it deletes the join_table references before. I'd preffer get a foreign key constraint eiter ^^.

Comment: After a fiew investigations I 've seen that the entry is deleted into the join table before.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem here.  If you delete or remove an EtyCharacter, it is upto your application to remove the reference to it in any EtyOeuvre characters lists and then merge this into the persistence unit either before deleting the EtyCharacter or within the same sequence/transaction.  Since the EtyOeuvre characters lists owns the relationship, only changes made to this collection will affect the join table in the database, but the application is responsible for ensuring both sides are maintained to keep the cache in sync with the database

Comment: thanks my english doesn't help ^^ . When I delete a character, jpa delete its references into the join table even if there aren't any. I thought the orm just tried to delete the characters and get a foreign key constraint. In this case EtyOeuvre is the owner of the relation and it's a bidirectional relation, so I can verify if the collection of Etyoeuvre, into an Etycharacters instance, is empty before delete.

Comment: If you still have references to the EtyCharacter instance, you are expected to get a foreign key constraint violation when the context is flushed or the transaction commits.  EclipseLink should not be deleting joint table references when you call remove on EtyCharacter based on the mappings you've shown.

Comment: but it does. I update my post to show the request it generate, I've activated the verbose mode into my persistence.xml.

Comment: There is more going on here, as EclipseLink would not delete a specific row ((characters_ID = 76) AND (oeuvres_ID = 1)), it would delete all the rows for that character using just (characters_ID = 76).  Looks like you might have cleaned up the reference in the EtyOeuvre characters list

Comment: I have another manyToMany relation, a 3-ways relation, so a jointable with three foreign keys and a class to map it. In this case the relations between the 3 entities and the join class are OneToMany. And if I delete one of the three entities which are referenced into the join class I get e foreign key constraint.